# Backbone - passing data while initializing collection's model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

This is how I currently handle the data passing to my collection's model. But I'm not really sure if this the best/correct way.

**MyCollection:**

```
define([ 'underscore',  'backbone','models/mymodel'], function(_, Backbone, myModel){
  var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: function (attr, options){
        options.data = {data: options.collection.options.some_data};
        return new myModel(attr, options);
    },

    initialize: function(options) {
        this.options = options;
    }

  });

  return MyCollection;
});
```

**MyModel:**

```
define([ 'underscore',  'backbone' ], function(_, Backbone){
  var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
    },

    initialize: function(attr, options) {
`       console.log(options.data)
    }
  });

  return MyModel;
});
```

Is this the only way to pass the data while initializing the collection's model?

Answer (score 1):

No, try this in MyCollection:

```
model: myModel,
```

And if you create a new myModel do this:

```
var model = new myModel({
     prop1: 'something', // etc
});
```

Comment: but I need to pass the data stored in collection to it's model.while it's being initialized.

Comment: a collections has one model, but contains a collection of multiple instances of this model. So what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: As it's stated above just to pass the data to the model. But I need the data to be available while the model is being initialized.

Answer (score 1):

You could override how a collection transforms a hash of attributes into a model. It is done via [`Collection._prepareModel`](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-139) and you would alter the options passed to this method:

```
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:  MyModel,

    _prepareModel: function(attrs, options) {
        options = _.extend({}, options, {
            data: this.options.some_data
        });

        return Backbone.Collection.prototype._prepareModel.call(this, attrs, options);
    },

    initialize: function(models, options) {
        // note that the options hash is the second argument
        this.options = options;
    }
});
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/jd5d8fmy/

Comment: was considering to use this, but it's almost the same as I'm currently using.